# Pasting issue in input field-Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I struck with a scenario where i am not able to move ahead actually I have an input field where I should recognise that user pasting data through `cmd+v` for that I have a code as fillowing

```
 public InputField _wordsEntry;

    if ( (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightCommand) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftCommand)) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V) || Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
            {

                if (EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject != null && EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name == "WordsEntry")
                {                   
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_wordsEntry.text))
                        _wordsEntry.text =ClipboardHelper.Clipboard;
                    else
                        _wordsEntry.text = _wordsEntry.text + '\n' + ClipboardHelper.Clipboard;
                    _wordsEntry.MoveTextEnd(false);
                }
            }
```

The issue is `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_wordsEntry.text))` this condition is always becoming as false.When I am trying to paste the copied content it is entering to `else` condition,is there any thing that I am missing?

Comment: try it like this: "String.IsNullOrEmpty(_wordsEntry.text)" (capital S) or like this: "_wordsEntry.text.IsNullOrEmpty()"

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm pretty sure that's the answer so I convert my comment to answer xd

try it like this:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(_wordsEntry.text) //(capital S)
```

or like this:

```
_wordsEntry.text.IsNullOrEmpty()
```

Comment: Thanks for help @Lestat,I tried first  way of Taking S but thats not worked for me and second case is not allowing.The value is assigning the to the text before pasting in input field.